# Error with sudo apt update. ign: 1 deb.debian.org

Tags: debian, apt, repository, software-updates

[image: Error]On my Debian Bookworm machine, packages using apt are not updated with errors *Ign:1 deb.debian.org/debian bookworm Inrelease... Ign:2 security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm Inrelease... Ign:3 deb. debian.org/debian bookworm-updates*. I tried to change the repositories in source.list, nothing changed. I think that this is not a DNS error, since I couldn’t get a response from the digital IP security.debian.com. Screenshot attached. Thank you

Comment: doesn't look like a DNS error to me. It would say that. What does the error message at the end, when you let it run to completion, say?

Comment: (also, we *much* prefer copy and pasted text over photos of screens.)

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/packages/InRelease - Temporary failure resolve deb.debian.com

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/bookworm-security/InRelease - Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (I set ip of this in etc/hosts file.

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/bookworm-updates/InRelease - Temporary failure resolving deb.debian.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dig +short security.debian.org
151.101.66.132
151.101.194.132
151.101.2.132
151.101.130.132
```

Security.debian.org has multiple IP addresses (and also multiple IPv6 addresses), both to spread the load to multiple physical servers, and to allow one of the physical servers to be down for maintenance without causing much inconvenience: if the clients cannot reach the IP address they got first, they are supposed to try the other addresses listed in the DNS response.

By setting a fixed IP address in the hosts file, you stop this round-robin mechanism from working: then you'll be stuck with either changing the IP in the hosts file, or waiting until your chosen server's maintenance break is over.

With HTTPS, you might also run into certificate validation issues if you use a raw IP address in the `apt` configuration.